# How can I play LA Noire on Mac?

Tags: macos, la-noire

I'd like to play with LA Noire (and other video games) on my Mac. The problem is that many games are not available for Mac computers. How can I play these games on my Mac, in good playable condition?

Comment: Aren't there official system specifications?

Comment: Would you be willing to use Wine?

Comment: Good idea. I should installing wine and then windows, right?

Comment: WINE (or another similar program, though WINE seems the most popular) is pretty much your only option to play Windows games on Mac, I think.  Of course, the "play with good conditions" stipulation will depend heavily on your Mac's capabilities, and it might be difficult to compare minimum specs intended for a PC to Mac hardware, if you're trying to figure out how well a game will run ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Wine, a virtual machine, or Bootcamp.

With Bootcamp you would be running Windows as your OS instead of Mac (but can switch between them), and it should run the best and have the highest chance of compatibility with the game.

With a virtual machine you would run a program that would run Windows while you're using Mac OS. This will have a good chance of compatibility with the game, but also requires a machine that surpasses the minimum system requirements because running multiple operating systems at once is likely to cause some performance issues.

With Wine you would still be using Mac OS, but Wine will translate the program as needed to make it work (as well as it can, which is not always so well).

Wine is the hardest to setup/learn, VM likely a close second, and Bootcamp the easiest. For me personally anyways.